# Batch Script merging PDFs with pdftk

Tags: batch-file, pdf, pdftk

Thanks in advance for any help given.

After searching through all relative threads and google search I'm stumped on finding a solution to output a variable name for merging two PDFs.

So I have hundreds of PDFs I need to combine (two at a time) in a folder `c:/test`

The files are set out like below

```
Company Name Invoice No 123456
Company Name Invoice No 123456 details
```

Now I have managed to move two files at a time to a different folder and merge them but can't seem to get the desrired output name I'm after which is to put a week ending date in front (or at the end,  not fussed) of the first merged filename. Below is the code I have thus far which works but the output file name is blank but gets created.

Very new to batch scripting and would appreciate any help :)

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe

set Source=C:\test
set Target=C:\test\test2
set num=2
set filenumber=1

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%\*.pdf"  ^|     findstr /n "^" ') do (
    if %%f leq %num% (
        copy "%source%\%%g" "%target%" /y > nul 
    ) else goto endCopy
)

:endCopy
endlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "%target%\*.pdf"  ^|      findstr /n "^" ') do (
    if %%f leq %filenumber% ( set file=%%~nA
   )
)
pdftk *.pdf cat output we_19_9_2017_%file%.pdf
```

Comment: Using the wrong meta variable. set file=%%~ng

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I'm still getting a blank output for the variable %file%

Comment: Remove the `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` lines. They are not needed for the code you are using.  The %filenumber% variable is no longer defined after the endlocal statement.

Answer (score 0):

In `endCopy` you are trying to get the name of `A` whereas you are iterating with `f`. Use `set file=%%~nf` to set the name of file or `set file=%%~ng` for second file.

And move `endlocal` at the end to expand `!file!` at the end of script like this (note the !):

```
:endCopy
set "cmd=dir /b /a-d "%target%\*.pdf" ^| findstr /n "^""
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in ('%cmd%') do if %%f leq %filenumber% set file=%%~nf

pdftk *.pdf cat output we_19_9_2017_!file!.pdf
endlocal
```

Read more about DelayedExpansion at: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Thanks @S.Ahmad for the info and suggestion, I've amended my code as you suggested but I was still getting a blank output file. I ran your code in console and got the error "FINDSTR: No search strings", I've tried some alterations but no luck....... any thoughts on the error?   Appreciate the help!

Comment: @manitou in your script you are passing double quotes to `findstr` which returns this error:

`dir /b | findstr /N ""

FINDSTR: No search strings`

You should add the string that you are searching for between `"^"` e.g. `"file^"`

Answer (score 0):

The last command doesn't use the target folder for the input files and thus looks for the input files in the current folder, so either include the path or first change to the target path.

Also you set a path-variable for pdftk but don't use it.
If this path isn't included in the `%path%` it can't be find.

Try this (untested)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe"

set "Source=C:\test"
set "Target=C:\test\test2"
set num=2
set filenumber=1

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in (
    'dir /b /a-d "%source%\*.pdf" ^| findstr /n "^" '
) do if %%f leq %num% (
    copy "%source%\%%g" "%target%" /y > nul 
) else goto endCopy

:endCopy
endlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in (
    'dir /b /a-d "%target%\*.pdf" ^|findstr /n "^" '
) do if %%f leq %filenumber% set file=%%~nf

PushD "%Target%"
"%pdftk%" *.pdf cat output we_19_9_2017_%file%.pdf
PopD
```

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, when the file is output the variable %file% is represented as '1'   ie  we_19_9_2017_1. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You initially set filenumber to one, the last if prohibits to get it larger so what do you expect?